# Перебор значений и подстановка в них максимальное

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Не могу сделать запрос, в котором будут перебираться значения, и потом делаться `UPDATE`.

Есть список `id`.
Надо пройти по нему и для каждого `id`, выбрать максимум из `Date_1` и `Date_2` и подставить в `Date_3`

Вроде бы у меня должно получиться что-то типа:

```
UPDATE table
SET Date_3 = (SELECT Max ( Date_1, Date_2, 
      --тут тоже нужно писать WHERE id = ??? )
     )
WHERE ...
```

если тут просто укажу `id` через `IN ()`, то ведь просто везде поставится максимальное `Date`?`

Работаю с MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам в каждой строке для указанных `id` надо в третий столбец вписать максимум из двух других, то ваш запрос будет иметь следующий вид

```
UPDATE table1
SET date3 = (case when date1 > date2 then date1 else date2 end)
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

функция `max`, которую вы хотите использовать, это агрегатная функция и применяется с столбцу вкупе с группировкой, так что в данном случае в таком виде не применима. Но в целом, с использованием подзапроса и `VALUES` можно и ее использовать.